# Steam not downloading games on ubuntu 16.04.1?

Tags: steam, downloads

So, I have managed to get steam to work and run in ubuntu 16.04.1 64 bit. And I decided to attempt to download some games. I tried downloading something small and noticed that the speed slowly went down. (My average download speed is about 350 kb/s). So it started at 240.5 kb/s download speed, and changed a little bit for the first few minutes. However it then started to get much slower for no reason. it dropped down, further and further. until it hit 0 kb/s. When I pause the download and start it again, it jumps up to my average, and then goes down. Now it does not even go up above a few kilobytes/s. Anyone experienced this or could have any idea what could be causing it?

I have tested it on 2 different machines (which both have good internet connection) and I also tried this in a VM where I got the same result.

I only have 2 GB of RAM and 4 GB swap memory enabled on the machine that I am currently experiencing this on. And yes, I have checked and made sure that I have enough disk space for the downloads.

If you have any further questions feel free to ask them, as this is quite inconvenient for me. Any responses/ideas welcome.

Thanks.

**EDIT:** Also, just for some more background info, I have never had this happen in windows on any machines before, and it only happens in ubuntu for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem, and it turned out that having the `sync` option set in `/etc/fstab` for the hard drive that my steam library is on was causing the problem. If you're installing games on a hard drive separate from your OS, go into `/etc/fstab` and make sure it isn't mounted with the `sync` option.

Answer (score 0):

I have had very similar symptoms while downloading games on a Windows machine. I would get decent rates for a few seconds and it would plummet and bottom out to a crawl, or just bad rates from the start

Try switching to a different download server. Steam should be able to continue a download without having to start over even after changing regions.

From steam client:
Steam > Settings > Downloads > Download Region